# Jquery onload/text effect late reaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app have this code:

```
window.onload = ->
  $("#mycontainer").typewriter()
  $("#div1").fadeIn("slow")
```

which acts on this:

```
  <blockquote class="pull-left">
       <p id="mycontainer">A mathematician, scientist, and engineer are each asked: "Suppose we define a horse's tail to be a leg. How many legs does a horse have?" The mathematician answers "5"; the scientist "1"; and the engineer says "But you can't do that! </p>
       <small id="author">Emmanuel Mensah </small>
  </blockquote>
```

Now, I can clearly see the `window.onload` function which I understand to let the jquery kick in right after the page loads. I realised that first, the page loads and then for a split second, I can see the (whole) text BEFORE the text effects comes in (effect is a typewriting which means text should not be visible but typed key after key...to the right). But I am wondering how to this so that when the page loads, I don't see the text at all but just after the `jquery` kicks in.

I tried to add this `CSS` `style: display:none` to the `<p>` tag but this changes nothing. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide them at first to see the showing effect.

```
window.onload = ->
  $("#mycontainer").hide()
  $("#div1").hide()
  $("#mycontainer").typewriter()
  $("#div1").fadeIn("slow")
```

Comment: Can you create a demo jsfiddle?

Comment: There is no text shown for the joke after loading. Then the characters appeared one by one as expected. I guess you can't see the update because of cache, either browser's or Rails'. Try to clean them.

Answer (score 0):

Try body onload instead.

```
<body onload="myfunction()">
  <blockquote class="pull-left">
    <p id="mycontainer" style="display:none;">A mathematician, scientist, and engineer are each asked: "Suppose we define a horse's tail to be a leg. How many legs does a horse have?" The mathematician answers "5"; the scientist "1"; and the engineer says "But you can't do that! </p>
    <small id="author">Emmanuel Mensah </small>
  </blockquote>
</body>

function myfunction() {
  $("#mycontainer").show();
  $("#mycontainer").typewriter();
}
```